# Add a column to a datagrid

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add a column with dropdownlist to a DataGrid

Here is the code for the DataGrid binding datasource

```
        List<CPDEmployee> employeelist = (List<CPDEmployee>)Cache["EmployeeList"];

        unverifiedlist.DataSource = employeelist;
        unverifiedlist.DataBind();
        unverifiedlist.AllowPaging = true;
        unverifiedlist.PageSize = 10;
```

In the page.aspx code is like this

```
 <asp:DataGrid ID="unverifiedlist" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanged="unverifiedlist_PageIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Surname" DataField="Surname" ReadOnly="true">   
                </asp:BoundColumn>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Options" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="options" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Verified</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Rejected</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText ="Reason">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="reason" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>
```

[image]

The result is there are two "Surname" fields in the datagrid. The reason I added "Surname" from page side is that i can't set the order of the columns (the dropdownlist should be at last).

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn off AutoGenerateColumns and specify *all* the bound fields.